# how set default value if cmd arguments is not set in getopt

Tags: python, getopt

I use getopt to parse command line arguments in python script. Is it possible to set default values for command line arguments?
I have following code:

```
try:
  opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"htt:tf:d:",["from=","to=","on="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
  print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
  sys.exit(2)
for opt, arg in opts:
  if opt == '-h':
    print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
    sys.exit()
  elif opt in ("-f", "--from"):
    fromTime = arg
  elif opt in ("-t", "--to"):
    toTime = arg
  elif opt in ("-d", "--on"):
    onDate = arg
```

So I need to do so if `from` is not set, `fromTime` should be set as some default value.

Comment: I recommend to use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html#id1) instead, based on getopt

Comment: It is not good idea for me as my script will be used for python version lower than 2.7

Comment: Which version will be used, the other one is [`optparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html#module-optparse), or just the basic `sys.argv` and do it with a else clause

Comment: Thanks, looks like otpparse is what I need

Comment: Glad I helped, I changed also the answer. If you want to close the question, mark an answer as useful, if it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With argparse, modified from the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/argparse.html#id1):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# The -- indicates that it is optional 
parser.add_argument("--verbosity", help="increase output verbosity") 
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.verbosity:
    print "verbosity turned on"
else:
    print "Default option"
```

This way if the optional argument is not added it will do the else statement. It adds also a help manual where you can explain all the options. And if it fails to interpret the arguments it automatically return the options of the script. (automatically does this `logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>`)

The OP in the comments state that argparse is out of consideration due to version problems.

The other options I see are [optparse,](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/optparse.html) or just the basic [sys.argv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) and do it with a else clause.

Answer (score 3):

With the built-in [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) package you can do this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-p', '--population',
                    required=False,
                    type=int,
                    default=100, 
                    dest="pop",
                    metavar="<number of individuals>",
                    help="Number of individuals in each population" )
parser.add_argument('-g', '--generation',
                    required=False,
                    type=int,
                    default=30, 
                    dest="ngen",
                    metavar="<number of generations>",
                    help="Number of generations to calculate" )
args = parser.parse_args()
```

As you can see: define argument type, default values, usage info, long and short versions of the argument, etc. Once instanciated, the values will be accesible through the object using its `dest` attribute. For example, the argument `-g` will be stored in `args.ngen`, and `-p` in `args.pop`.

Regarding the compatibility issues, argparse does work on Python => 2.3, according to its [pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse). Just install it or bundle it.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to just set the parameter value BEFORE you look at the args. If it is not specified on the command line, it'll have the default value:

```
try:   
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(argv,"htt:tf:d:",["from=","to=","on="])         
except getopt.GetoptError:
    print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'   
    sys.exit(2)

fromTime = Default_value

for opt, arg in opts:
    if opt == '-h':
        print 'logReader.py -f <from> -t <to> -d <on>'
        sys.exit()
    elif opt in ("-f", "--from"):
        fromTime = arg
    elif opt in ("-t", "--to"):
        toTime = arg
    elif opt in ("-d", "--on"):
        onDate = arg
```

if the user specifies `-f` or `--from` it'll over-ride the default. Just be sure to mention the default in your `-h` string.